# Android - how to refresh tab contents

Tags: android, tabs

I have two tabs with fragments created in my activity, the data of the second tab depends on the first tab data.

Both the tabs are containing list items, when I delete an item from first tab's list, it gets deleted but the second tab still shows the data. I need to go back from activity and load again to see the updated data in second tab.

Is there any way that I can refresh the second tab content whenever I delete/update list item of first tab?

Note: I have tried - 
`detach()`
`attach()`

and

`runQueryOnBackgroundThread()`
`notifyDataSetChanged()`

In `onResume` nothing seems to be working. Any help would help a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about Interface communication. Read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should override `setUserVisibleHint` method in your fragment and put your refreshing code in it

```
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
       if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {

       }
    }
```

I got this code in help.Hope it will help more people.Or refer my question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505019/how-to-refresh-tabs-content-dynamically-while-switching-between-one-tab-to-other/40505242#40505242